# Azure Function Scale out factors and warm up with timer trigger on Consumption Plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions

What are the scale out factors for Azure Function on Consumption Plan?

If i have a Azure Function with a time trigger running once every 5 mins
will this keep my functions in warm state and running normally forever?

In addition to above, will the scale out work if there are background threads processing running that requires more Azure Functions instances?

What about auto scale in when the background threading reduces resources usage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan

[Azure Functions Timer Trigger Scale-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520084/azure-functions-timer-trigger-scale-out)

[How do Azure Functions scale out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311598/how-do-azure-functions-scale-out)

Answer (score 3):

1. Scale-out factors vary by trigger type. For example, an HTTP-triggered function's scaling depends on request concurrency, while a queue-triggered function's scaling depends on queue depth.
2. If you have a timer trigger that runs once every 5 minutes, your function app will always be loaded onto one instance. You'll be able to avoid a complete cold start (from 0 instances) this way. However, a scale-out will require your app to be loaded onto another instance. The time taken to load your app onto the new instance will incur a delay for those requests. If you want a constant low latency with autoscaling, you may want to look at the [premium hosting plan.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#premium-plan)
3. Background thread processes have no direct effect on the consumption plan's scaling logic.
4. This is possible, but not guaranteed. Example: if background threading is slowing processing of queue items in a function, the queue depth may increase to the point that it scales out.

Comment: Thanks, so you confirm that on 2, scale out with Timer trigger and background thread is possible. What is point 4, "This is possible"?

Comment: re: 2, no; if you only have a timer trigger and a background thread, neither will trigger scale-out; timer triggered functions only ever execute on one instance, and the consumption plan's scale controller doesn't look at CPU/memory. Scaling decisions are made based on trigger-related metrics (see #1). re: 4, "This is possible" means that scaling may be impacted by background threads if they consume memory and CPU to the point they slow (non timer triggered) function invocations and cause, for example, a buildup of queue messages. I don't recommend relying on this.

Comment: on point 4: you meant scale out? What about auto scale in when the background threading reduces resources usage, as mentioned on last paragraph on OP.